# Switch from input type=file to text field depending on category

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, forms

I want to switch from input type=file to a text field depending on the selected category. The whole form would go through the same php code which handles the upload functions.

This is my form:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uploadForm">
     <div>
      <select name="category">
       <option value="pho" selected>Images</option>
       <option value="vid">Video</option>
       <option value="pap">Paper</option>
      </select>
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="file"/>
      <p>Title: <input type="text" name="f-title" id="f-title" cols="40" rows="5" class="fullWidth"/>
      </p>
      <p>Description:</p>
      <textarea type="text" name="f-desc" id="f-desc" cols="40" rows="5" class="fullWidth"></textarea>
      <p>
       <label class="radio">Portfolio</label>
       <input type="radio" name="folio" value="TRUE" checked/> <span class="radio">Yes</span>
       <input type="radio" name="folio" value="FALSE"/> <span class="radio">No</span>
      </p>
    
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit"/>
     </div>
    </form>
```

As you can see, I want to handle 3 types: image, pdf and video. For the video type, I want to be able to paste a youtube link in the form, which will be eventually saved in the database and shown in the gallery of the website. But if I just add the link, the file upload would be empty. The other way around too: if I add the image, the link would be empty.

What would be the best way to switch between these document types?
PS: Javascript or jquery is fine!

Comment: Are you willing to use any JavaScript to solve this? Because that would be the easiest/fastest/ **probably** the best way.

Comment: I would recommend you to have multiple input elements for each of the category, and then based on which category chosen, show proper element (using javascript). Then on the server side just pick proper value from the post, based on the category value.

Comment: I would suggest following @PavelGalaton's advice in this instance. It's a much cleaner solution than changing your element type after the DOM loaded it - and depending on how you lay it out, you could even do the switch with CSS

Comment: I agree with Sina. Using JS would be the best way. However if you really want to use php then PavelGalaton's advice is the way to go. If you are still not satisfied then you can do html '"onchange='<?php echo "<input type='input type' name='input name' multiple id='your id'/>"; ?>"'. **note:** _This only works if the file is '.php' format_

Comment: oh sorry, probably wasn't clear enough. Javascript or jQuery is fine :). I already have some, so no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select')
      .change(function() {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
          case 'pho':
            $('#file').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#form-description').addClass('hidden');
            break;
          case 'vid':
          case 'pap':
            $('#form-description').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#file').addClass('hidden');
            break;
        }
      });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uploadForm">
    <div>
      <select name="category">
        <option value="pho" selected="">Images</option>
        <option value="vid">Video</option>
        <option value="pap">Paper</option>
      </select>
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" id="file" />
      <p>Title:
        <input type="text" name="f-title" id="f-title" cols="40" rows="5" class="fullWidth" />
      </p>
      <div id="form-description" class="hidden">
        <p>Description:</p>
        <textarea type="text" name="f-desc" id="f-desc" cols="40" rows="5" class="fullWidth"></textarea>
      </div>
      <p>
        <label class="radio">Portfolio</label>
        <input type="radio" name="folio" value="TRUE" checked="" />
        <span class="radio">Yes</span>
        <input type="radio" name="folio" value="FALSE" />
        <span class="radio">No</span>
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

The best way is show proper element based on choosed category

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid javascript, I think there's a way to do what you want using only css. It would involve adding different inputs for media, text, etc, but they would be visible or not depending on the type selected by the user. I was able to make this work with pure css only using radio buttons - I couldn't make the select work:

```
<style>
    .oneVisible, .twoVisible, .threeVisible {
      display: none;
    }

    #mediaType[value=one]:checked ~ .oneVisible {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #mediaType[value=two]:checked ~ .twoVisible {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    #mediaType[value=three]:checked ~ .threeVisible {
      display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<input type="radio" name="mediaType" id="mediaType" value="one" checked />One<br />
<input type="radio" name="mediaType" id="mediaType" value="two" />Two<br />
<input type="radio" name="mediaType" id="mediaType" value="three" />Three<br />

<input type="text" class="oneVisible" placeholder="for one" />
<input type="text" class="twoVisible" placeholder="for two" />
<input type="text" class="threeVisible" placeholder="for three" />
```

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3bfwt6t4/). This shows you how to make different inputs visible with different selections. On the server side, all inputs would still be present, so you would have to choose which to use based on the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

The below will do exactly what you asked for (according to my understanding).

No extra css or html added to your existing code.

```js
/* CHOOSE EITHER WAY */

// jQuery way
$('[name=category]').on('change', function(e){
    var target = $(e.target),
        input = $('#file');
    if (target.val() === 'vid')
        input.attr('type', 'text');
    else
        input.attr('type', 'file');
});


// Javascript way
document.getElementsByName('category')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var target = e.target,
        input = document.getElementById('file');
    if (target.value === 'vid')
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    else
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="uploadForm">
    <div>
     <select name="category" id="category">
      <option value="pho" selected>Images</option>
      <option value="vid">Video</option>
      <option value="pap">Paper</option>
     </select>
     <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="file"/>
     <p>Title: <input type="text" name="f-title" id="f-title" cols="40" rows="5" class="fullWidth"/>
     </p>
     <p>Description:</p>
     <textarea type="text" name="f-desc" id="f-desc" cols="40" rows="5" class="fullWidth"></textarea>
     <p>
         <label class="radio">Portfolio</label>
         <input type="radio" name="folio" value="TRUE" checked/> <span class="radio">Yes</span>
       <input type="radio" name="folio" value="FALSE"/> <span class="radio">No</span>
     </p>
    
       <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```